# Laravel 5.4 Mix ignore img in SCSS

Tags: laravel-5, sass, laravel-mix

I try to use Laravel 5.4 mix with SCSS, but it gives me and error

```
error  in ./mysite/assets/sass/landing/landing.scss

Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error 
Can't resolve '../img/somepic.png' in
'/var/www/html/mysite/resources/assets/sass/landing'`
```

in

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/landing/landing.scss', 'public/css/landing.css');
```

However, I don't want to resolve pics at all, I just want them to stay as they were.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the problem with

```
mix.options({
  processCssUrls: false
});
```

in webpack.mix.js